# Sorting Mongoose populate() with a condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’m currently using `populate()` like so:

Schemas:

```
  var DefinitionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String, 
    slug: String, 
    description: String
  });
  DefinitionSchema.index({description: 'text'});
  DefinitionSchema.plugin(textSearch);

  var SectionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      heading: String,
      intro: String,
      alpha: false,
      definitions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Definition' }]
  });

  var PageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    time : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
    title: String, 
    slug: String, 
    intro: String,
    body: String,  
    sections: [SectionSchema]
  });
```

Page rendering:

```
exports.edit = function(req, res){
    Page.findOne({ slug: req.param('page') }, function(err, page){
        res.render('admin/page_edit', { page: page});
    })
    .populate({path: 'sections.definitions', options: {sort: {slug: 'asc'}}});
};
```

This means that `sections.definitions` are sorted alphabetically for every section.

I was wondering whether it was possible to pass a condition to the `sort` within `populate`, so that I can change the sorting based on the value of (the parent document) `section.alpha`.

I figured it would look like this:

```
function sorting(section) {
    var sort = {}
    if (section.alpha) {
        sort = {slug: 'ace'}
    }
    return sort;
}

query
...
.populate({path: 'sections.definitions', options: {sort: sorting(sections)}});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by moving `res.render` into the `exec` function, and performing the `sort` at that point:

```
exports.edit = function(req, res){
    Page.findOne({ slug: req.param('page') })
    .populate({path: 'sections.definitions'}).exec(function(err, page){
        page.sections.forEach(function(section) {           
            if (section.alpha) {
                section.definitions.sort({title: 'asc'});   
            }
        })
        res.render('admin/page_edit', { page: page});
    })
};
```